# In html,how to make a variable,how to check if something exists in a variable

Tags: html

I am creating a signup and sign in for my website,so users type their info in signup then they can sign in,i want to store their info so that when they type their info in the sign in,if their info exists,they can enter to the website.
Here is the code of my sign up code:

```
<form>
Name: <input type="text" name="Name/"><br/>
Email:<input tpye="email" name="Email"/><br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="Password"/><br/>
Gender:<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Gender"/>Male<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Gender"/>Female<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And here is my sign in code:

```
Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Also i want to make sure that the user enters all the info needed,like name pass and email.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this only with HTML.
You need a server-side scripting language like php, asp, jsp and a database to store data too.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to store the data? You need a database like MySQL. You also need a server side scripting language like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a variable in HTML.  You may want to look into javascript to do some client side scripting and ajax to contact the server.

Comment: Ajax is rarely appropriate for a sign up or login form.

Comment: @Quentin could you explain why?

Comment: Because the thing it is best at is changing a small part of a page, and logins don't result in a small state change.